# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, ios, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-cosmosdb

I am currently working on a project using Visual studio 2017 on Mac.
The application is a native C# Multiplatform app for iOS and android with Xamarin.

[image]

I am trying to interface with the CosmosDB database provided by Microsoft azure an am using the package [Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/) installed through NuGet

When initializing my client the same way as the examples in the [getting started tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started) using

```
new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);
```

However, internally, I get the exception

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

[image]

I am new to visual studio and was wondering what could be causing this problem. another package installed is 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices'
Do I have to add this package to add this dll to my references? If so where can I find it?

Here is the 'packages.config' file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Amqp" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Devices" version="1.16.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared" version="1.15.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" version="1.22.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.3" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Net.WebSockets.Client" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XmlDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.AccessControl" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Permissions" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Principal.Windows" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Try installing this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/

Comment: <Reference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager">
          <HintPath>..\packages\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>

Comment: Is actually in the .csproj file of the iOS project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB is not compatible with Xamarin. Everything works fine if instead we use [Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core/)

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, you could try to install `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` to ensure Configuration contain [ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/) attrribute.

If you are using VS for Mac then currently you will need to add one `PackageReference` into the `.csproj` manually by using a text editor.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.4.0.280" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/107093/dependency-loading-error-when-using-a-net-standard-xamarin-forms-project-in-an-ios-app).

Comment: The application in question is not a Xamarin forms app. It is the Native app (screenshot update in post). Ive still tried to add this package reference without any success.